# How to change the value of a client-side variable from the Meteor shell?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In `/lib/global.js` I have:

```
footerButtons = ['x','y','z'];
```

I use this in a client-side Spacebars helper:

```
Template.footer.helpers({
  footerButtons: function(){
    return footerButtons;
  }
});
```

Then from the meteor shell I do:

```
footerButtons = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

After I ran this the client-side helper did not update.

Can a Meteor shell command change a client-side variable value?

Comment: Yes. I added more explanation to my question. :)

Comment: No, updating the variable in the meteor shell will not affect its value on the client. Generally, you would use a publication to affect changes like that on the client from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor shell interfaces directly with the server.  While `footerButtons` is defined on both the client and the server, the Meteor shell command you execute will only affect the server value.  Since there isn't reactivity built-in on a global variable like that, your `footerButtons` client value doesn't change.  You'd have to use a Meteor.method or something to get the value from the server.